# Taxonomy Terms node count of different content type along with zero count in a hierarchy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

After much headache I was able to maintain a kind of hierarchy for the taxonomy terms, of the already continuing issue here, please click the below link

[Taxonomy Terms node count of different content type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96989/taxonomy-terms-node-count-of-different-content-type)

I did It like this, but still needs to do more.

In second step select the parent relation and check the exclude display.
[image: screenshot]

Under format option select the parent taxonomy under group 1

[image]

I am getting the parent category under  tag and the child terms as list-terms. using jquery I can display it in an accordion style somehow.

[image]

Now the problem i am facing is that empty taxonomy terms with counter zero are not getting displayed, please help if anyone knows the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check what you have set for the "no results" behaviour on that field. You will not want it set to "hide".

Also check if it displays in the views preview. If it displays there but not on your page then it may be that your template is checking if a field is blank and before deciding whether to show it - you could solve this by setting a default/no results value of "0"

Comment: I unchecked the check box "Hide if empty" for this particular field but unfortunately empty terms are not shown, even not in view preview.

Comment: Try entering "0" (zero) in the "no results behaviour text" box. This should put the number zero when there are no results rather than just not displaying the item. Not sure if this will not cause the number 1 to appear as there is now a value so test and see.

Comment: I tried with number "0" but nothing happens, may be some other way..

Comment: Actually by adding reverse relation in relationships the empty terms gets hidden...

Comment: Does anyone founds any solution for this....