# Display Empty taxonomy terms using views

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Hi I am displaying my taxonomy terms using views having a reverse node relationship added, I am able to display the taxonomy terms having nodes associated with it, but I am not able to display the empty terms which have "0"zero count.

I need to also display the empty terms. I have enabled the aggregation for node counter. Help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Adding taxonomy terms with aggregation enabled]

[image: Node reverse relationship]

I am using views version 3. Actually this question is related to this link also

[Taxonomy Terms node count of different content type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96989/taxonomy-terms-node-count-of-different-content-type)

This solved my thing but I need to display the empty terms also.

Comment: What version of Views is it? And could you turn module names into links to project pages? Would make it easier for us to investigate it.

Comment: I am using views version 3. Actually this question is related to this link also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96989/taxonomy-terms-node-count-of-different-content-type, This solved my thing but I need to display the empty terms also.

Comment: Please use edit link to provide clarifications. Comments are like yellow postit notes, they can disappear pretty much any time and nobody would really care ;)

Comment: may be altering the view(with hook_views_query_alter() function) can help?

Comment: Thanks but how can we show the empty categories by altering the view, I dont have much knowledge over custom coding. If you can help in some way, that would be really appreciable.

Comment: While clicking on the taxonomy term name field in a view i am getting a "no result behavior" link, I clicked on it and unchecked the option "hide if empty" but unfortunately this has no effect. empty terms are still hidden. I dont know for what purpose this option is there?.. if any has some idea then please let me know